# ContentResolver from ProviderTestRule doesn't notify ContentObserver

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-contentresolver, kotlin-flow, turbine

I'm trying to test my `Flow` based `ContentResolver` extension function:

```
abstract class Query {
    abstract suspend fun runQuery(): Cursor?
}

private val mainThread = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

fun ContentResolver.observeQuery(
    uri: Uri,
    projection: Array<String>? = null,
    selection: String? = null,
    selectionArgs: Array<String>? = null,
    sortOrder: String? = null,
    notifyForDescendants: Boolean = true
): Flow<Query> {
    val query: Query = object : Query() {
        override suspend fun runQuery(): Cursor? {
            return query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)
        }
    }

    return callbackFlow {
        val observer: ContentObserver = object : ContentObserver(mainThread) {
            override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
                trySend(query)
            }
        }

        registerContentObserver(uri, notifyForDescendants, observer)

        awaitClose {
            unregisterContentObserver(observer)
        }
    }.onStart {
        emit(query)
    }
}
```

Here's my androidTest code written using [Cash App's Turbine Flow testing library](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine).

```
class KiteContentResolverTest {

    private val dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @get:Rule
    val providerRule: ProviderTestRule = ProviderTestRule
        .Builder(TestContentProvider::class.java, AUTHORITY.authority!!)
        .build()

    private val contentResolver: ContentResolver
        get() = providerRule.resolver

    @Test
    fun testCreateQueryObservesInsert() = runBlockingTest {
        contentResolver.observeQuery(TABLE).flowOn(dispatcher).test {
            awaitItem().runQuery()!!.isExhausted()
            contentResolver.insert(TABLE, values("key1", "val1"))
            //Code suspends here and never receives another item.
            awaitItem().runQuery()!!
                .hasRow("key1", "val1")
                .isExhausted()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testCreateQueryObservesUpdate() = runBlockingTest {
        contentResolver.insert(TABLE, values("key1", "val1"))
        contentResolver.observeQuery(TABLE).flowOn(dispatcher).test {
            awaitItem().runQuery()!!.hasRow("key1", "val1").isExhausted()
            contentResolver.update(TABLE, values("key1", "val2"), null, null)
            //Code suspends here and never receives another item.
            awaitItem().runQuery()!!.hasRow("key1", "val2").isExhausted()
        }
    }

    companion object {

        private val AUTHORITY: Uri = Uri.parse("content://test_authority")
        private val TABLE: Uri = AUTHORITY.buildUpon().appendPath("test_table").build()
        private const val KEY = "test_key"
        private const val VALUE = "test_value"
    }
}
```

And my mock ContentProvider

```
class TestContentProvider: ContentProvider() {
    private val storage: MutableMap<String, String> = LinkedHashMap()
    
    private val contentResolver: ContentResolver
        get() = context!!.contentResolver
    
    ...
    override fun insert(uri: Uri, values: ContentValues?): Uri? {
        values ?: return null
        storage[values.getAsString(KEY)] = values.getAsString(VALUE)
        contentResolver.notifyChange(uri, null)
        return Uri.parse(AUTHORITY.toString() + "/" + values.getAsString(KEY))
    }

    override fun update(
        uri: Uri,
        values: ContentValues?,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<String>?
    ): Int {
        values ?: return storage.size
        for (key in storage.keys) {
            storage[key] = values.getAsString(VALUE)
        }
        contentResolver.notifyChange(uri, null)
        return storage.size
    }

    override fun query(
        uri: Uri,
        projection: Array<String>?,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<String>?,
        sortOrder: String?
    ): Cursor {
        val result = MatrixCursor(arrayOf(KEY, VALUE))
        for ((key, value) in storage) {
            result.addRow(arrayOf<Any>(key, value))
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

However, It seems like the `ContentObserver` is never actually called when my data is inserted or updated. And my tests always fail with this stack trace:

`kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCancellationException: Timed out waiting for 1000 ms`

Oddly, enough when I run this code on a real device using the actual MediaStore `ContentResolver` the code executes and the flow emits new values as expected.

It would seem to me that the `ContentResolver` provided by the `ProviderTestRule` simply doesn't work with content observers. Has anyone else figured out a way to observer mock ContentResolvers in this way?

Comment: I've made some progress on this issue. It looks like [TestProviderRule](https://androidx.de/androidx/test/rule/provider/ProviderTestRule.html#build()) returns a ContentReaolver backed by [MockContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/test/mock/MockContentResolver#notifychange) which states "Overrides the behavior from the parent class to completely ignore any content notifications sent to this object". So it looks like you can't rely on a ContentObserver to function in this use case. Not really sure what the best path forward is though.

Comment: However, these tests pass if I rewrite them to use `ProviderTestCase2` which is now deprecated. But that is surprising because it would appear that `ProviderTestCase2` utilizes the same `MockContentResolver` that `TestProviderRule` relies on which fails to notify observers.